# Ubiquitous keyboard shortcut for Find Next in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, find

First I added a single-key shortcut for Find Next that works "When: Editing Java Source". Then I added the same shortcut for "When: Comparing in an Editor". However, none of these shortcuts has any effect in comparison view (Right-click / Compare With / ...).

How can I create a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse that works in any kind of editor as well as in both panes in the compare view?

Comment: In my case, it's still not working: I have binded "F3" to every "Find Next" action present (When "Editing Text", "Embedded Xtext Editor context" and "In Windows", but when I do a search and afterwards I press "F3", nothing happens.

I believe that the problem is somewhere in the "Wnen" condition: is there any way to know "what I am doing", I mean how can I know if I'm editing text, if I'm in Windows, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Its not easy, but I can be done. It actually has to be done one at a time where you want <kbd>F3</kbd> to work. This is not a complete example, but will hopefully give the idea.

Step 1:
Start by binding <kbd>F3</kbd> to to "Find Next" in windows (windows is the most general). This will get <kbd>F3</kbd> to work in java code and jsp code. However this will NOT make <kbd>F3</kbd> work in JavaScript code.

Step 2:
Copy the key binding you just made. In the copy change when the binding occurs from windows to JavaScriptView. Note that a conflict occurs. You will need to deal with the conflict in the usual way, by either unbinding the other command or binding it to a new key. At that point, <kbd>F3</kbd> works in Java, JSP, and JavaScript code.

As you find other places where you want <kbd>F3</kbd> to mean "Find Next" simply repeat Step 2 above for that location.

Note: Tested under Eclipse version 3.5.2

Comment: The problem is there is no location called "Console" like there is "Windows", "JavaScript", etc

Comment: (At least in Eclipse 4.9.0) there is "In Console View", but it does not seem to work.